# Maven "test" command is not working from command line, works everything fine with eclilpse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am facing "JRE" error while executing "test" command from command line but "clean" command is working fine also I have tried after configuring the "JDK" path in environment variables but still issue is not resolved.

System Variable:

```
Name:JAVA_HOME , value:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

I tried to configure path variable as well:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
echo %JAVA_HOME%
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
echo %PATH%
```

After configuring above I am observing below error :

```
PS F:\softy\workspace_softy\farziBada2> mvn clean
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

I have configured `JAVA_HOME` perior to `PATH` variable but then `mvn clean`
also not works

Nothing works.

In Eclipse I have pointed jdk path as compiler, both the commands works fine.
Output for MVN Test:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building farziBada2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ farziBada2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ farziBada2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ farziBada2 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ farziBada2 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to F:\softy\workspace_softy\farziBada2\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.175 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-15T03:49:20+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project farziBada2: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Output for MVN Clean:
mvn clean:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building farziBada2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ farziBada2 ---
[INFO] Deleting F:\softy\workspace_softy\farziBada2\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.275 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-15T03:55:23+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try change to `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;`  move `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` prior to `%PATH%`,  I guess  the JRE  configured in the System Environment Variable, which prior to User Environment Variable.  If you put `%PATH%` ahead,  the JRE will be first found.  you can check the output of  `echo %PATH%`, then check how many JRE and JDK install folder appear in the output, and which one appear firstly.

Comment: @yong Thanks for the help
It works after setting `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;` prior to the `PATH` variable :)